# Passing from centralized workflow to a distributed one

Tags: git, web, version-control

This is the rudimentary way we currently work in our team (4 people developing). I'm putting pressure on them to change it, but I need a plan and I need to convince them. Our current workflow:

[image: Primal way]

And this is what I think we should accomplish:

[image: Decent way]

As you see, there's currently one GIT repo: it's in our development server. But we all directly work on it since it's mounted as a network drive and the project in our IDE's is based on it.

Once tested we commit on it, and use FTP to upload these committed files to the production server. We never use git push, and there's only one branch (master). It's useless to have more working this way with several users on the same repo.

A very primitive way to do this I know. GIT is only serving us as a history. It's obviously becoming a nightmare of "hey don't touch this, I'm on it now" and things like that.

So my main question is, what are the steps we should take to achieve the second diagram (or whatever else you'd rather suggest)? One thing to note is that our constant daily workflow is to receive tickets/orders, change and deploy.

My first idea would be to clone the development repo in every local machine. Problems that could arise:

- The development repo has a working tree currently (the one on which we all are working on).
- Since we work on web development, we need to constantly test every little change. So we would end up needing to continually push to the development server to test any change and see how it works (I think the only solution for this would be to use Vagrant and a virtual machine on every local machine).

What should we change in our development server's repo? 
How should we set up the repo in the production server, and link it to the development one?

Finally, having in mind the workflow I explained, what would be the best approach regarding branches?

I've read it would be better to always have a production/build branch checked out in the production server, and when the testing on the development branch in the dev server is approved, merge it to the production/buld one, then pull from the production server.

Comment: YOu might want to consider gitflow's workflow. https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows

Comment: @Edmundo Thanks. I knew that workflow but it seems too sophisticated for our needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert diagram1 workflow to diagram2, you can follow these steps:

1.Change the development server as remote repo (remote repo is bare, no working directory)

```
# In a different directory
mkdir develop
cd develop
git init --bare
# In the development server folder
git remote add origin \path\for\the\develop\you\just\created
git push origin --all
# Now the new create folder develop is the really development server repo (below steps mean the new one).
```

2.Change the production server as a bare repo as step1 if it’s not bare now.

3.Change the way between local repo and development server repo.

```
# In separate local repo
git clone /path/of/development/server
git pull 
git commit
git push
```

4.Change the way to deliver changes from development server to production server

```
# In development server
git remote add pro /path/for/production/server
git push pro --all
```

Or you can use **post-receive hook** to update production server automatically.

For the local repo, it just relative with the remote repo (development server). And since your code is based on web, so you can clone git repo to virtual machine, vagrant or network drive as the local repo.

> What should we change in our development server's repo? How should we
>   set up the repo in the production server, and link it to the
>   development one?

As in step1, the important thing is to make development server as a bare repo. Also, you should change production server as a bare repo. To link development, you can add remote in development server, and then push changes to production server. Or use post-receive hook, this will automatically update production when local repo finish pushing to development repo.

Whether to work on master branch or new created branches. There are some situation to work on new branch:

- Changes from developers need to be approved before applying the changes on master branch
- Develop new features/ fix bugs need to test by other roles (such as QA) before applying on master branch

In a word, if it’s ok for all developers to make changes on master branch directly, you can use only master branch. Else, developers can commit/push changes for their own, the approver then merge these changes to master branch.

For production server, if development and production server not always sync, of cause you can have a production branch to deal with merge/pull for developmetn server.

There is [a successful branch modle](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) with different branches for you to refer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will consider it, since it seems quite clear. There are questions I have though: I'm not sure what would be the role of the development server if whenever I push to it from local, a post-receive hook would immediately push to production. Another question: wouldn't it be better to create the remote from the production server (pointing to development) in order to always do a pull from it instead of pushing from the dev one?

Comment: Development server (remote repo) is the place where your code is version controlled, local repo is just working copies for the remote repo. Yes, post-receive hook will immediately push to production after local changes are pushed to development. No, if you want to pull changes to the new create one, the new create one must be local repo not remote. Because `git pull` used to pull changes from remote, and `git push` used to push local repo to remote, they are opposite with each other.

Comment: But if any push to development will be immediately pushed to production, it will lose its role of testing server right? It will be just an intermediate bridge. We should only test in local repos (e.g. via Vagrant). Another thing that confuses me a lot is, how can a server like production work (and serve files to the users in our case) if it won't have a working directory? I mean, there will not be files and directories there. Just the metadata in the .git directory, right?

Comment: If you don't want to push production automatically, you can use the commands in step4 (add production as a remote,the push to it when you are ready). The remote repo contains files and folder as `.git` does. And it save different versions as sha-1 values in `objects` folder. You can refer git book to have further understanding, such as https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Comment: So all in all I understand that a bare repo will have the same versioned files/directories as in a not bare one, but somehow they will not be available to be edited? I will look into the link you provided. It's something I don't have clear at all.

Comment: Yes, as you found, you can't edit the bare repo. We usually edit it in working copies (local repo). The function of the bare one it to record the versions you changed, and it's not recommend to change it directly. And you can use `git clone`, `git pull` and `git push` to modify it indirectly.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! :)